# OpenShift "Cannot read property 'start' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I have troubles setting up node.js in OpenShift.

I have set up my package.json like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Chat",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

I get the following error when I push:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 776, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (709/709), done.
Writing objects: 100% (776/776), 715.32 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 776 (delta 136), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: [eval]:1
remote: var p = require('/var/lib/openshift/57d037442d5271a3570000ea/app-root/runtime/repo//package.json'); console.log(p.scripts.start);
remote:                                                                                                                          ^
remote:
remote: TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
remote:     at [eval]:1:122
remote:     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:25:33)
remote:     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:77:17)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
remote:     at bootstrap_node.js:357:29
remote:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
remote:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
remote: [eval]:1
remote: var p = require('/var/lib/openshift/57d037442d5271a3570000ea/app-root/runtime/repo//package.json'); console.log(p.scripts.stop || '');
remote:                                                                                                                          ^
remote:
remote: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined
remote:     at [eval]:1:122
remote:     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:25:33)
remote:     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:77:17)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
remote:     at bootstrap_node.js:357:29
remote:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
remote:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Stopping Node.js application...
Connection to oak-drabble.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly*
```

When I use npm start it works well. I never used OpenShift so I don't know if I'm missing something. I kept the start.js script in my repo and I don't know if I should have.

Any ideas on the issue ?

Comment: Maybe it's not picking up the `package.json` file properly, have you tried just `console.log(p.scripts)`?

Comment: Where should I write this ? I only have a simple express web app in server.js and a html file for the moment

Comment: Is that line something OpenShift is doing?  The `remote: var p = require('/var/lib/openshift/57d037442d5271a3570000ea/app-root/runtime/repo//package.json'); console.log(p.scripts.start);`

You're getting another error right below it for a `stop`.

What kind of framework/codebase did you start the App with?

Comment: I can't find it anywhere in the folder. I use express.js and socket.io and Node.js version 6.4.0

Comment: That means it's something included in the framework you picked when you setup the App in OpenShift.  Which one did you use?

Comment: Node.js Auto-Updating (6.4.0)

Comment: Can you post the file structure.  I dug through that cartridge on GitHub, and it may have something to do with where you placed the `package.json` file.

Comment: I solved the issue by using another cartbridge. 

In the root directory there was : node_modules, public (folder with images and css), index.html, server.js, package.json

Comment: If the package.json file wasn't at the root, that was what caused your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using the Node.js 0.10 cartbridge instead of Node.js (Latest)